# Trouble installing Idris on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cabal, idris

Not sure if this site is the best place for asking such a question but I've already posted on r/Idris, see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Idris/comments/6hw2cz/trouble_installing_idris/).

I initially ran `$cabal update` and `$cabal install idris` and it failed because distributive-0.5.2 failed to install. Since then I've tried deleting and reinstalling cabal, deleting and reinstalling the Haskell Platform, playing with directories, following installation instructions for Debian, etc. It always comes down to the failure of distributive-0.5.2 to install. Any ideas?

Update: as suggested by noobninja I ran `$cabal install Distributive --reinstall` which failed to load interface "Distribution.Extra.Doctest" because there are files missing in "cabal-doctest-1.0.2." I then ran `ghc-pkg-check` and got a huge list of errors.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 I found Distributive in this dir `~/.cabal/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.10.3`. Distributive installed successfully on my system. You might try `cabal install Distributive` or `cabal install Distributive --reinstall` if Distributive is there. I have heard of users running out of memory while installing. Here is a ref. `https://ci.appveyor.com/project/idrislang/idris-dev/build/1.0.837` Here is Distributive @ github `https://github.com/ekmett/distributive/`

Comment: noobninja See update

Comment: I also tried downloading from github then installing idris, didn't work. Tried reinstalling Distributive and it failed

Comment: you mentioned *doctest*. I found this issue: `https://github.com/ekmett/distributive/issues/30` titled _ghc-options: -Wall and doctest #30_

Comment: @noobninja looks like the guy who started that issue committed "Adds cabal doctest" to resolve the issue. Could  a bug in that commit be the source of the issue?

Comment: [These instructions](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Installing-an-Idris-Development-version-in-a-sandbox) work well for me. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 too.

Comment: do not use Haskell Platform. it installs a lot of packages, hence the bigger the chance of version conflict. 
i recommend you purge Haskell Platform, clean the GHC cache, reinstall GHC, Cabal and install idris with cabal in a sandbox

Comment: @eben-cowley That is what I was thinking. Since that issue mentions both `distributive-0.5.2` and _doctest_.

Comment: @eben-cowley I do not have **Haskell** installed. So I do not have **doctest** installed. Could there be a **Haskell/Idris conflict**? Here is another ref. `https://www.reddit.com/r/Idris/comments/6hw2cz/trouble_installing_idris/`